# How to install PHRETS 2.0 using Composer in live website.

Tags: php, composer-php, phrets, mls

I am working on MLS implementation & Received rets login url, User Name & Password.

I installed in localhost & folders uploaded in live but not working.

[How to install PHRETS 2.0 using Composer in live website. I have little bit knowledge. By WHM using SSH command I can do that! Is it right way?]

I have tried to connect using phrets.php (version 1.0.1) & By Installing PHRETS 2.0 (https://github.com/troydavisson/PHRETS).
In both cases - Not Connect message came.

Using RETS Connector 1.2 (http://www.retsconnector.com/Home/ConnectorDownload). **I would able to connect to server.** & using their task, able to received .csv file (But not images?).

** Firewall Test Pass for: rets.torontomls.net:6103, PHP 5.6+ version in my live website.

Anyone can help me out.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the image links with RETS Connector 1.2 by checking the All Media on the Media tab. Cancel when you are asked to "Browse for Folder"  and the checkbox for "Add locations to Data file" will be enabled.  Check it if it doesn't automatically do so.